# Terraform - Check If Variable Ends With String & Remove

Tags: replace, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We've set up our TF GKE code so that the user can specify either the region or zone for the cluster.
However, we need to then check this variable and remove the zone suffix (if it exists) for the deployment of static IP addresses.

We have the following variable:

```
variable "k8s_cluster_location" {
  type        = string
  default     = "europe-west2"
  validation {
    condition = contains(["europe-west2", "europe-west2-a", "europe-west2-b", "europe-west2-c", "us-east4", "us-east4-a", "us-east4-b", "us-east4-c", "europe-west1", "europe-west1-a", "europe-west1-b", "europe-west1-c" ], var.k8s_cluster_location)
    error_message = "Given GCP location not (yet) supported. Contact X if you think it should..."
  }
  description = "Location of the Kubernetes cluster."
}
```

If, for example, the variable is "europe-west2-a", we need to remove "-a" to acquire the parent region.

Would we need to incorporate a Regex check? Or could we use something like StartsWith()/EndsWith()?

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend the regular expression solution here as you suggest:

```
variable "k8s_cluster_location" {
  type        = string
  default     = "europe-west2"
  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("(?:europe-west[12])|(?:us-east4)", var.k8s_cluster_location))
    error_message = "Given GCP location not (yet) supported. Contact X if you think it should..."
  }
  description = "Location of the Kubernetes cluster."
}
```

Note that if you are using Terraform 1.3.x, then you can also use the `var.k8s_cluster_location` value in the `error_message` instead of "Given GCP location".

For your other suggestion of `startswith()`, you would need to do something like `anytrue(startswith(var.k8s_cluster_location, "europe-west1"), startswith(var.k8s_cluster_location, "europe-west2"), startswith(var.k8s_cluster_location, "us-east4"))`, but that feels slightly messier to me.

Comment: The `anytrue` argument could itself be an expanded `for` expression over a set of prefixes, which would then avoid restating `startswith(var.k8s_cluster_location, ` for each one. But with that said: the regex does seem generally more compact and seems like it might be easier to read as a systematic rule rather than as a flat allowlist, so I'm mentioning this only for completeness!

Comment: @MartinAtkins I believe I also subconsciously prefer the former because it functions in Packer as well, whereas `anytrue` was not part of the HCL2 roadmap for Adrien and Megan during 1.5.x-1.7.x.